# multiply dropdown list value with a constant

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to multiply the value from the dropdown list by a certain value say $10 and the value ALL multiply it by $7 and for the value to appear in the text box. I am totally new at scripting and would appreciate any help.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Amount:<br>
<select><br>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
</select>
<br>
<td>Total: <input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="text" value="$0.00" size="3" /></td>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the value `All` should be? does it the sum of all list values or what?

Comment: Offtopic: You don't need `<br>` inside `<select>`. Actually you don't need `<br>` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just give an id to your select field like "mySelect" use the following javascript code:

```
var selectElement = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    selectElement.addEventListener('change',myFunction);
    function myFunction() {
        var value = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
        if(value=="ALL")
        value=7;
        var fixedAmount=10;
        document.getElementById("quantity").value = '$'+fixedAmount*value;
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your help ankit, I'm having trouble making the resulting multiplication show in the text box. I already placed the id like <id="mySelect">Amount as you said but the result does not show in the box.

Comment: could you provide your modified code..i'll see how its not working

Comment: Thanks ankit, I made it work. Sorry to answer so late but I was out for a while. I appreciate your help.